# How to replace "$10" with "10 dollars" using regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have some phrases like below:

```
This is not my spending '$10', this is companys spending: '$250 million' and this is some other figure: '$200,000'.
```

that I would like to remove the dollar symbols and add "dollar" at the end of phrase, like this:

```
This is not my spending '10 dollars', this is companys spending: '250 million dollars' and this is some other figure: '200000 dollars'.
```

I now have regex to match(`[£\$€][\s\d,\d]+(|million|billion|trillion)`), but I haven't been able to get the substitution part right.

How do I do this?

Comment: On every phrase you will always have a $ at the start of it?

Comment: You could use re.sub to replace all symbols in your initial string with "" and then add dollars at the end?

Comment: Naveen, comparing your expected output, I think you also need to remove any commas that are thousand separators, right? It is not mentioned in your answer, and when answering only having in mind the expected output may not be understood by other users, and sometimes leads to unwelcome actions. Please precise your requirements. Also, please clarify if you want to replace `€` with `euros`, and `£` with `pounds`.

Comment: yes, @LidorEliyahuShelef, $ always occurs before the numbers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the initial example I gave in my question was very bad. yes, i want to replace `€` with `euros`, and `£` with `pounds`. for $ symbol, I am matching with `(\$)([ ,\.\d]+(?:million|billion|trillion|))` and substituting with `\2 dollars `.

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala I can see someone already gave you an answer, if you'll need any more help, edit your question or raise another on and tell us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following function to achieve what you described.

```
import re

def adjust_dollars(text):
  text = re.sub(r'^\$', '', text)
  text = re.sub(r'(.$)', r'\1 dollars', text)
  return text
```

Test run:

```
words = ['$10', '$250 million', '$200,000']
result = map(adjust_dollars, words)
print(list(result))
```

Output:

```
['10 dollars', '250 million dollars', '200,000 dollars']
```

Comment: since my question was about substitution, i chose this answer. for dollar, regex worked is `([\$])([ \.,\d]+)(million|billion|trillion|)`(inspired by tobiak's answer) and substitution is `\2 \3 dollars `. more: https://regex101.com/r/qmKFVj/1

Answer (score 1):

Just an example with re.sub:

```
t1 = "$10"
t2 = "$250 million"
t3 = "$200,000"

sub_pattern = "/$|," #Look for dollar signs or commas
tail = " dollars"
re.sub(sub_pattern,"",t1) + tail -> 10 dollars
re.sub(sub_pattern,"",t2) + tail -> 250 million dollars
re.sub(sub_pattern,"",t3) + tail -> 200000 dollars
```

Comment: So if you can find using match the portions of the string that needs to be changed. You can use re.sub to substitute string patterns with some replacement as needed. Consider using a conditional check to substitute the tails with dollars or euros or pounds for example.

Answer (score 1):

Since your regex also includes symbols for Pound and Euro, I assume not all of those start with `$`. Then you could use `re.sub` with a callback-function to determine the currency to use. This also works if the currencies appear in the middle of the text.

```
import re
p = "([£\$€])\s?([,\d]+(?: million| billion| trillion|))"
d = {"$": "dollars", "£": "pounds", "€": "euros"}

text = "I have $10 and £3 million and €100,000 trillion"
print(re.sub(p, lambda m: f"{m.group(2)} {d[m.group(1)]}", text))
# I have 10 dollars and 3 million pounds and 100,000 trillion euros
```

Also note some subtle changes to the regex: I put the currency symbols in a group, so it can be accessed later, and put the "empty" suffix at the end, otherwise it's greedily matched first and none of the others. Also, no need to put `\d` twice in `[...]`, and better move the space to the suffix part.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your strings start with "$" you don't need to use regex. just select them at second character with "[1:]" and add " dollars" at the end. for example if your string store in variable named a:

```
a[1:] + " dollars"
```